# Paragraph breaks in 2 when adding link element

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have this wicked problem only in Firefox: when I add a link element to a contentEditable paragraph sometimes it breaks the paragraph in 2 or 3. This doesn't show any error and sometimes takes few seconds. Here's the code:

```
function changeSelectedText(type,text) {
  var selObj = window.getSelection();
  var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
  var newElement = document.createElement(type);
  if(type == "a") {
    newElement.setAttribute('href', text.toLowerCase());
    newElement.setAttribute('target', "_blank");
  } else if(type == "span"){
    newElement.setAttribute('class', "big");
  }
  var documentFragment = selRange.extractContents();
  newElement.appendChild(documentFragment);
  selRange.insertNode(newElement);
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(newElement);
  selObj.removeAllRanges();
  selObj.addRange(range);
}
```

Adding span works perfect but with links it sometimes causes this strange behavior. Any idea why?

Here's the link to jsfiddle like Mike suggested:
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dariuszpietrala/AtPkd/2/)

Comment: can you put this in a jsfiddle so we can see the same thing happening?

Comment: Thanks @mike-pomax-kamermans for the reply. The link is in the main post. It works without any problems :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it :) The problem was that the button that I used for adding the link (the #link div at jsfiddle) sometimes got selected (only FF). I thought that the mousedown function should prevent this from happening but it didn't. So, what I did is I've added js to prevent selecting that button:

```
 <div id="#link" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;">Add Link</div>
```

If anybody has some better solution let me know ;)